# Comparing lists of field-hashes with equivalent AR-objects

Tags: ruby, activerecord, hash, identity, set

I have a list of hashes, as such:

```
incoming_links = [
 {:title => 'blah1', :url => "http://blah.com/post/1"},
 {:title => 'blah2', :url => "http://blah.com/post/2"},
 {:title => 'blah3', :url => "http://blah.com/post/3"}]
```

And an ActiveRecord model which has fields in the database with *some* matching rows, say:

```
Link.all => 
[<Link#2 @title='blah2' @url='...post/2'>,
 <Link#3 @title='blah3' @url='...post/3'>,
 <Link#4 @title='blah4' @url='...post/4'>]
```

I'd like to do set operations on `Link.all` with `incoming_links` so that I can figure out that `<Link#4 ...>` is not in the set of `incoming_links`, and `{:title => 'blah1', :url =>'http://blah.com/post/1'}` is not in the `Link.all` set, like so:

```
#pseudocode
#incoming_links =  as above
links = Link.all
expired_links = links - incoming_links
missing_links = incoming_links - links
expired_links.destroy
missing_links.each{|link| Link.create(link)}
```

Crappy solution a):

I'd rather not rewrite `Array#-` and such, and I'm okay with converting `incoming_links` to a set of unsaved `Link` objects; so I've tried overwriting `hash` `eql?` and so on in `Link` so that it ignored the `id` equality that `AR::Base` provides by default. But this is the only place this sort of equality should be considered in the application - in other places the Link#id default identity is required. Is there some way I could subclass Link and apply the `hash`, `eql?`, etc overwriting there?

Crappy solution b):

The other route I've tried is to pull out the attributes hash for each Link and doing a `.slice('id',...etc)` to prune the hashes down. But this requires writing seperate `-` methods for keeping track of the Link objects while doing set operations on the hashes, and writing seperate Proxy classes to wrap the `incoming_links` hashes and Links, which seems a bit overkill. Nonetheless, this is the [current solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747811/comparing-lists-of-field-hashes-with-equivalent-ar-objects/2760386#2760386) for me.

Can you think of a better way to design this interaction? Extra credit for cleanliness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirements are:

```
#  Keep track of original link objects when 
#   comparing against a set of incomplete `attributes` hashes.
#  Don't alter the `hash` and `eql?` methods of Link permanently, 
#   or globally, throughout the application.
```

The current solution is in effect using Hash's `eql?` method, and annotating the hashes with the original objects:

```
class LinkComp < Hash
  LINK_COLS = [:title, :url]
  attr_accessor :link
  def self.[](args)
    if args.first.is_a?(Link) #not necessary for the algorithm, 
                              #but nice for finding typos and logic errors
      links = args.collect do |lnk|
         lk = super(lnk.attributes.slice(*(LINK_COLS.collect(&:to_s)).to_a)
         lk.link = lnk
         lk
      end
    elsif args.blank?
       []
    #else #raise error for finding typos
    end        
  end
end

incoming_links = [
 {:title => 'blah1', :url => "http://blah.com/post/1"},
 {:title => 'blah2', :url => "http://blah.com/post/2"},
 {:title => 'blah3', :url => "http://blah.com/post/3"}]

#Link.all => 
#[<Link#2 @title='blah2' @url='...post/2'>,
# <Link#3 @title='blah3' @url='...post/3'>,
# <Link#4 @title='blah4' @url='...post/4'>]

incoming_links= LinkComp[incoming_links.collect{|i| Link.new(i)}]
links = LinkComp[Link.all] #As per fl00r's suggestion 
                           #this could be :select'd down somewhat, w.l.o.g.

missing_links =  (incoming_links - links).collect(&:link)
expired_links = (links - incoming_links).collect(&:link)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
incoming_links = [
 {:title => 'blah1', :url => "http://blah.com/post/1"},
 {:title => 'blah2', :url => "http://blah.com/post/2"},
 {:title => 'blah3', :url => "http://blah.com/post/3"}]

ar_links = Link.all(:select => 'title, url').map(&:attributes)

# wich incoming links are not in ar_links
incoming_links - ar_links

# and vice versa
ar_links - incoming_links
```

**upd**

For your Link model:

```
def self.not_in_array(array)
  keys = array.first.keys
  all.reject do |item|
    hash = {}
    keys.each { |k| hash[k] = item.send(k) }
    array.include? hash
  end
end

def self.not_in_class(array)
  keys = array.first.keys
  class_array = []
  all.each do |item|
    hash = {}
    keys.each { |k| hash[k] = item.send(k) }
    class_array << hash
  end
  array - class_array
end

ar = [{:title => 'blah1', :url => 'http://blah.com/ddd'}]
Link.not_in_array ar
#=> all links from Link model which not in `ar`
Link.not_in_class ar
#=> all links from `ar` which not in your Link model
```

Comment: One of the key points is to keep the Link objects around, and know which have been excluded. To do so with your `:select` suggestion, I'd have to do the second thing I spoke of - write a class or method which does the subtraction while keeping the Link object ids around.


Only loading the fields that I need is an interesting idea though, for when I need to speed this whole process up.

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite the equality method, will ActiveRecord complain still?

Can't you do something similar to this (as in a regular ruby class):

```
class Link
  attr_reader :title, :url

  def initialize(title, url)
    @title = title
    @url = url
  end

  def eql?(another_link)
    self.title == another_link.title and self.url == another_link.url
  end

  def hash
     title.hash * url.hash
  end
end

aa = [Link.new('a', 'url1'), Link.new('b', 'url2')]
bb = [Link.new('a', 'url1'), Link.new('d', 'url4')]

(aa - bb).each{|x| puts x.title}
```

Comment: Do you think this would work as a subclass of Link? That way I could alter eql? and hash, but not do so globally. I fear the ActiveRecord association internals, and what they'd do with overwritten `hash` and `eql?` methods, but if this was a subclass (call it, say, LinkComp) I might be able to #becomes(LinkComp) to all the `links` and `incoming_links.collect{|il| LinkComp.new(li)}`. I might try this.